# Как добавить Mime-type правило в GAE-сервере?

Tags: mime, java, google-app-engine

Не нашел, как можно добавить mime-type правило в Google-App-Engine сервере (java). 
Попробовал написать в файле web.xml:

```
  <mime-mapping>
      <extension>jnlp</extension>
      <mime-type>application/x-java-jnlp-file</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

Не помогло.

Comment: Так вы смотрели что на самом деле возвращает сервер? Посмотрите HTTP заголовки

Comment: В запросе нигде нет application/x-java-jnlp-file в заголовках. Там какая-то хитрая вещь про статические файлы и файлы ресурсов на официальном сайте написано. Может попробовать тэг <a type="application/x-java-jnlp-file" href="my.jnlp">...</a>. Хотя ясно, что нужно как-то выставить этот Mime-type на сервере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, задать таким образом mime type правило можно [только для статическиx файлов](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Changing_the_MIME_Type_for_Static_Files), а для файлов ресурсов нужно создавать jsp страницу.

Answer (score 0):

Не имею возможности проверить, но есть ещё способ задать MIME-тип через app.yaml

```
- url: /path/to/file.jnlp
static_files: path/to/file.jnlp
mime_type: application/x-java-jnlp-file
expiration: "30m"
upload: path/to/file.jnlp
```

Comment: Это для сервера на питоне. А у нас Java. Там нет никаких app.yaml. Только appengine-web.xml и web.xml